# How can I modify this C# code so that Visual Studio recognizes that I'm not an idiot?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 lines that go

```
int selectedOrgId; 

foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs)
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
         selectedOrgId = o.orgid;

PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category {
    orgid = selectedOrgId,
    catname = newCatName
});
```

The middle line, the loop, is guaranteed, in the context of my program, to set a value for `selectedOrgId`. However, Visual Studio is flagging the last line because

> Use of unassigned local variable 'selectedOrgId'

What is a way to solve this other than

```
int selectedOrgId = 69; 

foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs)
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
         selectedOrgId = o.orgid;

PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category {
    orgid = selectedOrgId,
    catname = newCatName
});
```

????

Although it works, it seems like an inelegant solution, since it involves a magic number. I want to know the proper C# style of solving this.

**EDIT:**

Looking at some of the discussion here, I should've specified that there is only such `orgid` in the database. My `foreach` statement should've been written like

```
foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs)
{
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
    {
         selectedOrgId = o.orgid;
         break;
    }
 }
```

Thanks for showing me some ways to better do this whole thing!

Comment: a bold statement for any developer to make

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't know anything about the context of your program...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417595/best-practice-for-initializing-object-attributes-in-oo-languages) states that best practice is to let it fail then run silently with a bad value.  I would suggest, if you want to do an exception if selectOrgId is 0 after the loop.  This would make your code much more intentional.

Comment: The reason it is complaining is because `selectedOrgId` may never get set because of the `If` statement on line 2.  If it never gets set then it will have an uninitialized value when you try to use it on the 3rd line which could cause problems.  You need to make sure that a value gets set on all code paths, or change your logic to only use that variable when it has a known valid value.  IMHO Visual Studio is right to warn you about this code.

Comment: This seems like a problem that should be easily  resolved without having to learn Linq. int? should do it

Comment: Gave you a star for sense of humor. Thanks for making my day. :)

Comment: @Jonesy What is a bold statement?

Comment: @FiredfromAmazon.com `that I'm not an idiot`

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you're iterating through a collection, trying to find a single matching value based on the organization name. You can use LINQ's `SingleOrDefault()` to find (at most) one match:

```
var selectedOrg = PD.orgs.SingleOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName);
```

Then only call `InsertOnSubmit()` if a value is found: *(otherwise, selectedOrg will be null)*

```
if (selectedOrg != null)
    PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { orgid = selectedOrg.orgid, catname = newCatName });
```

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

What happens if the condition `o.orgname == selectedOrgName` is not satisfied for any value in `PD.orgs`? Then `selectedOrgId` will be left uninitialized.

However, the following code might be more 'elegant' according to your approach:

```
int selectedOrgId = PD.orgs.Single(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName).orgid;
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { orgid = selectedOrgId, catname = newCatName });
```

Please note that your code will set `selectedOrgId` to the last instance of it, while mine will assume that only one exists.

Comment: This also throws an exception if no match is found or more than one match is found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `int?`:

```
int? selectedOrgId = null;

foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs)
{
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
    {
         selectedOrgId = o.orgid;
    }  
 }

 PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category 
 { 
        orgid = selectedOrgId,
        catname = newCatName 
 });
```

Comment: What's the point of "int?" and assigning null to it when you can simply assign 0 to the variable? Besides, Category.orgid is not nullable.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz because you want to be able to tell the diffrence between a id of 0 and no id found. The OP never showed what orgid was.

Comment: @Mehrzad 0 might be a valid value for an `int`. While `null` indicates an "empty value" in this case, which is completely different.

Comment: Category.orgid is not nullable, since he didn't provided more info, you can't assume it is nullable  and/or null is valid or zero is invalid.

Comment: In this case the null value is acting like a flag to indicate that there was no matching `orgName`.

Comment: It's not clear that his objects have nullable int properties, so for category orgid you would need to do selectedOrgId.GetValueOrDefault().  This, I feel, just confuses the code more.

Comment: The braces here different than the original question. The `PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit` happens outside the foreach. For example, try running this: `foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5)) if (true) Console.WriteLine(i); Console.WriteLine("finally here");`

Comment: @JasonWilczak Even if his code isn't nullable, he may make it so if he wants to indicate a value wasn't found. Not sure what the big fuss around the nullability is all about.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830592/why-shouldnt-i-always-use-nullable-types-in-c-sharp) is a nice discussion on the usage of nullables.  The basic idea is that sometimes you can't help it (data from databases), but, when you can, used a primitive type.

Comment: @JasonWilczak It's definitely a nice discussion, but it is also a matter of flavor. I see nothing wrong with using a nullable in this case, although other answers which use LINQ are as good (or may be even better) than this solution. It is still a possibility.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You are making an assumption that is not proved to be right. Actually no answer could be given to the question until OP tells us what behavior is expected when specified "Organization" is not found.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Yes, I am making an assumption. You seem to be really bothered by that fact, not sure why. If it isn't possible or doesn't fit the OPs needs then he can discard it, plenty of great answers provided to his problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov at least you could include the assumption in the answer. Actually everybody are making an assumption and throwing an answer. Yea OP will use the answers hopefully. I let it go :D.

Comment: I've edited my post to make clear that I'm looking for a single record

Comment: THIS, TAKES THE VALUE OUT FROM THE LOOP AND ELIMINATES THE WARNING WHICH WAS THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM, SO, REMOVE THE DOWNVOTES AND MARK IT AS THE CORRECT ANSWER

Answer (score 2):

Edit: OP changed the question to specify that only one item will ever be found and a multiple solution isn't needed, here is Option 1a

**Option 1a - One line Linq method**

This provides a single line linq query that will filter out the unnecessary orgs, grab the single item and select a new Category object to be used as the param for your insert.  This method WILL throw an exception if the single item cannot be located, but that is explicitly, what should happen based on your question.

```
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(
    PD.orgs.Where(o=>o.orgname==selectedOrgName)
    .Single()
    .Select(o=>new Category { orgid = o.orgId, catname = newCatName })
);
```

**Option 1b - Iterate a filtered list and perform work**

All of the other answers here suggest using linq and assume that only one record will ever be found.  Why not just do everything in the loop and use linq to filter the results?

```
foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs.Where(o=>o.orgname==selectedOrgName)) 
{
    PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { orgid = o.orgId, catname = newCatName });
}
```

The benefit here is no if statements and it handles single or multiple cases.  There is a way to make this on one line and remove the explicit for each and use List.ForEach ([see the comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225937/foreach-vs-somelist-foreach)):

```
PD.orgs.Where(o=>o.orgname==selectedOrgName).ToList()
.ForEach(o=>PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { orgid = o.orgId, catname = newCatName }));
```

**Option 2 - Use an exception**

This will make it very clear what your code intentions are and let Visual Studio know that you have this taken care of.  The idea is to keep your code very close to the way it is now:

```
int selectedOrgId; 
foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs) 
{
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName) 
       selectedOrgId = o.orgid;
}
```

However, at this point I would suggest you use an exception, such as:

```
if(selectedOrgId == 0) throw new InvalidDataException("Selected Org Id cannot be 0");
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { orgid = selectedOrgId, catname = newCatName });
```

Comment: But you ARE using Linq

Comment: @JAT you are correct, my fingers got away from me.  I edited the text to make my point more clear.

Comment: @JAT: He wasn't saying he wasn't.  He was saying that, unlike other answers suggesting Linq, his accounts for more than one record found.

Comment: Like the idea.  Hate the horizontal scrolling.  :P

Comment: @cHao Ok, but it's clear to me that the OP is looking for a single record

Comment: `List.ForEach` is not a LINQ method.  In fact, it's a method that is very much contrary to the goals and coding style of LINQ.  The "more LINQ" solution is to use `foreach`, not `ForEach`.

Comment: @Servy thank you for pointing that out, i rephrased my statement for accuracy.

Comment: I've edited my post to make clear that I'm looking for a single record

Comment: @FiredfromAmazon.com Ok, I've edited my answer to include a single item only variation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the only problem. You know you will find 1 or more matches, the compiler doesn't.

But the "or more" is also a problem. The code just isn't clear about what you want, that's the root cause. You have an implicit "last one wins" strategy.

When you use a solution that matches the requirement more closely, the compiler problem goes away without any hacks.

Without Linq:

```
// int selectedOrgId; 

foreach (Organization o in PD.orgs)
    if (o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
    {
       PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category {
         orgid = o.orgid,
         catname = newCatName
      }); 
      return;   // or break;
    }
// shouldn't get here
throw new ...
```

And with Linq

```
Organization org =  PD.orgs.Single(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName);
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category {
          orgid = selectedOrgId,
          catname = newCatName
       });
```

The `Single(Predicate)` method closely matches your problem. It will throw when the resultset has != 1 element.

Comment: selectedOrgId exists only inside the loop, OP wants it outside

Comment: @JAT: there is no "outside the loop" anymore, and there shouldn't be. Read it carefully.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, what's the point of having  `int selectedOrgId = o.orgid;` inside the loop if you can't use it elsewhere?

Comment: You could eliminate that easily but I left it to stay close to the original code. It really doesn't matter.

Comment: If you're not going to use anywhere else just do:  `PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category {
         orgid = o.orgid,
         catname = newCatName});`

Comment: Um, I still think the point of all this, is that the OP wants to get the value out from the loop, so can use it in the method scope, but who knows.

Comment: @JAT - The code is incomplete but the so far as we can see the InsertOnSubmit is the only use case.

Comment: I guess my question is how would you get the value out from the loop without using Linq, nullable int?

Comment: The answer is that you shouldn't want to.

Comment: Looking at your experience and reputation I suppose you're right, but I don't know why.

Comment: @JAT:  I think you're looking for the wrong kind of 'flexible' usage. This code runs under the assumption of exactly 1 result, it should express and use that assumption. And preferably break (throw) when the assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use [linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to select the org with the `selectedOrgName` and get the `orgid`:

```
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { 
    orgid = PD.orgs.First(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName).orgid, 
    catname = newCatName
});
```

---

That assumes `selectedOrgName` will always be in `PD.orgs` and I'm making that assumption based on the variable name; however, if that isn't always the case, you can do the following:

```
var selectedOrg = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName);

if (selectedOrg != null)
{
    PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { 
        orgid = selectedOrg.orgid, 
        catname = newCatName
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the exact equivalent of what your code does, but it will throw an exception if you ever don't have an org that matches (which you say can't happen):

```
PD.cats.InsertOnSubmit(new Category { 
    orgid = PD.orgs.Last(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName).orgid, 
    catname = newCatName
});
```